# SVG image not showing up in ios devices

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG image on my page with the following properties:

```
<svg role="img" height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
```

Problem: I can see the image on desktop versions but it's not appearing in ios devices (tried on iphone 6s safari).
I inspected the elements in ios device and the code is present but the portion containing the image is blank.

Edit: Content of the svg is:

[image]

Comment: What is the content of the SVG?

Comment: @Sean I've updated the content in my question.

Comment: Can you post it as code rather than a screenshot?

Comment: you have 2 groups with with an invalid transformation. Try adding a comma: `transform="translate(0,4)"` Also I see you have an empty `<mask>`. If this doesn't help please edit the question and add the code not an image of it